# How to find the distribution of the following random parameters?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I have two random variables $a$ and $b$, both are from uniform distribution Uniform[1,10].

I generate a large number of instances of $a$ and $b$. Lets say $N$ instances of $a$ and $b$. As a result, I have $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_N\in \text{Uniform [1, 10]}$  and $b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_N\in \text{Uniform [1, 10]}$.

Now,  $d_1=a_1/(a_1+b_1)$

If I want to calculate the distribution of $e_1,e_2,\cdots, e_N$ where $e_1=a_1-d_1$. What is the distribution of variables $e_1,\cdots,e_N$?

$\bf{EDIT}$:

I have three random variables $a$, $b$ and $c$, all are from uniform distribution Uniform[1,10].

I generate a large number of instances of $a$ and $b$. Lets say $N$ instances of $a$ $b$ and $c$. As a result, I have $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_N\in \text{Uniform [1, 10]}$  and $b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_N\in \text{Uniform [1, 10]}$, and $c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_N\in \text{Uniform [1, 10]}$.

Now,  $d_n=B_T\times a_n/(a_n+b_n+c_n)$

$B_T$ is a fixed values, lets say it is 10.

If I want to calculate the distribution of $e_1,e_2,\cdots, e_N$ where $e_n=a_n-d_n$. What is the distribution of variables $e_1,\cdots,e_N$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call $f_A$ the probability density function of the variable $A$, $A\sim \mathcal{U}(0, 10)$. $B$ also follows a similar distribution $B\sim \mathcal{U}(0, 10)$. Now, let $C$ be the random variable defined as

$$
c = a - \frac{a}{a + b} \quad\Rightarrow\quad b = -a - \frac{a}{c-a} \tag{1}
$$

If $A$ and $B$ are independent then the cumulative distribution function of $C$ is simply

$$
F_C(c) = P(C \le c) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\rm d}a\; P(C \le c | A = a) f_A(a) \tag{2}
$$

Taking the derivative w.r.t $c$ in both sides and using (1) we get

\begin{eqnarray}
f_C(c) &=& \frac{{\rm d}F_C(c)}{{\rm d}c} = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\rm d}a\; f_B\left(-a - \frac{a}{c-a} \right) f_A(a)\frac{{\rm d}b}{{\rm d}a} \\
&=& \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\rm d}a\; f_B\left(-a - \frac{a}{c-a} \right) f_A(a)\frac{a}{(c-a)^2} \tag{3}
\end{eqnarray}

This integral is quite large and I'm not going to include it here, but you can use [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) to calculate it. Below is a small simulation of the variable $C$, the histogram is by generating $10^5$ of samples for both $A$ and $B$ and calculating $C$ following Eq. (1). The dashed line is Eq. (3)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Please have a look at my edit. Do I get a normal distribution, Why?

Comment: @DipankarNarayanan No, it is not, this new distribution will have a singularity at $e = 0$

Comment: however, when I draw the histogram, I get a normal distribution like shape....

Comment: @DipankarNarayanan Do you want to post your result at the bottom of your question?